# Can you run later version of chromedriver (RobotFramework) on an updated version of Google Chrome?

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am beginning to test with the robotframework and am unable to generate a test because when I try to run chromedriver, since the version we are using to test is version 81, and my version of Google Chrome is version 83, it wont allow me to run the scripts. I was wondering if there was any way to work around this or downgrade my Google Chrome?

Any help would be appreciated!Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it reports an error that there's a mismatch of version, then probably you have one of the three options:

1. downgrade your Chrome - how to do that depends ony your operating system, but you don't mention that, so google the detail for your case
2. upgrade your Chromedriver version, more on that [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)
3. use a different driver and browser, firefox for example; but you still need to get compatible version of the two

There's no reason for trying to hack your way around it, just get compatible versions of the two and run your tests.